# How to find out the reason of ServiceHost Faulted event

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, servicehost

I have got a *MyServiceBase* class which inherits from ServiceBase. Inside MyService I Have got a ServiceHost for my WCF-service, whic has only one method with IsOneWay=true property. I used this code to initialize it:

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
host.Opened += new EventHandler(host_Opened);
host.Closed += new EventHandler(host_Closed);
host.Faulted += new EventHandler(host_Faulted);
host.UnknownMessageReceived += new EventHandler<UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs>(host_UnknownMessageReceived);
host.Open();
```

Sometimes host raises Faulted event, but EventArgs in *host_Faulted* method are always empty, so I cannot find out the reason of it.
Please help.
Thanks in regard.

Comment: I have tried to use pseudovariables (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx) but I didn't see $exception variable in locals window

Comment: Don't forget to leave a parameter-less constructor in your Host implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link might prove usefull for better ways of WCF Fault handling and debugging:

[How do I prevent a WCF service from enter a faulted state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315736/how-do-i-prevent-a-wcf-service-from-enter-a-faulted-state)

So instead of answering your specific question, i am recommending a better way of achieving your requirement.

Comment: This is helpful but did not answer the actual question. How does one get the exception stack that caused the service to fault?

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem today.  By enabling WCF Tracing, it helps, but did not give me the reason.  After lots of debugging work, I found the real reason is: Client which consumes WCF services crashed. Since the client is a wrapped Windows Service, and its status is still 'running'.

So my suggestion is: try/catch all the code blocks in your client application.