# WCF Service hosted in windows Service goes to faulted state

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, msmq

We have a WCF service hosted on windows service.
We are using **netMsmqBinding** binding. The job of service is upload some data to S3 storage.
After sometime on Production environment the service goes to faulted state.
We are unable to reproduce the issue on local environment.

How can we identify why the service goes to faulted state

Comment: Descripe "after sometime"? What part is failing? Do you have log in the different part that will help you narrow the scope? For now the question is just "_I have something somewhere that do stuff, but sometimes don't_". So we can only do random guess. My bet on "You have a service client in your code that you initialise in the windows service. The connection stay alive when you test but after some innactivity it goes down. And nothing check if it's not falted/close and reopen"

Comment: We have nothing in exception log but it goes down and i have no way to check whether the service is faulted /close or reopen

Comment: Here you can refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315736/how-do-i-prevent-a-wcf-service-from-enter-a-faulted-state